# How to Check if Text Exists on a Particular Element (not Page) with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

I want to run `$x` on a specific element, not the whole page, and tried this:

```
let selector = await page.$('.myClass"]');
let [el] = await selector.$x(`//p[contains(text(), 'myTextString')]`);
pass = el ? true : false
```

I'm expecting pass to evaluate to `false`, because the element with `myClass` does not contain `myTextString`, but `el` is not falsy because `myTextString` exists elsewhere on the page.

Is there a way to check for a string of text on a particular element?

Code to recreate the issue with `$x`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function test() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--start-maximized'] 
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');

  //  select a header div with no text content
  let selector = await page.$('#notify-container');
  //  an element is still found, even though I'm running $x on the selector, not the page
  let [el] = await selector.$x(`//h2[contains(text(), 'Find the best answer to your technical question, help others answer theirs')]`);

  console.log(el);

  await browser.close();
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandlexexpression), "The method evaluates the XPath expression relative to the elementHandle as its context node". So you just need to use the context node symbol in the beginning of the XPath: `.//h2` instead of `//h2`.